# singleton pattern implementation in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We need to implement some singleton pattern to ensure a stored procedure cannot be run several times simultaneously.

As I cannot see this functionality in place, I thought about implementing this via a "Lock" table.
We are in a "batch" environment so waiting a few seconds is no problem.

```
SHARED.LOCK(LOCK_NAME           STRING NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
           ,SESSION_ID          STRING NOT NULL
           ,ACQUIRED_AT         TIMESTAMP_NTZ
           )
```

- LOCK_NAME is forced to upper case and used as a Primary Key
- SESSION_ID is the current session
- ACQUIRED_AT is just useful information

I then create a stored proc to "acquire" the lock $LOCK_NAME that tries to update the lock record with its own session id as long as it is not "locked" already

```
UPDATE SHARED.LOCK
  SET LOAD_ID = $LOAD_ID
     ,SESSION_ID = CURRENT_SESSION()
     ,ACQUIRED_AT = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
  WHERE LOCK_NAME = $LOCK_NAME
    AND SESSION_ID IS NULL;
```

To avoid Snowflake optimistic locking side effects, I would ensure that this stored procedure is not called as part of an explicit transaction.

I then check whether I successfully "acquired" this lock

```
SELECT 1
  FROM SHARED.LOCK
  WHERE LOCK_NAME = $LOCK_NAME
    AND LOAD_ID = $SESSION_ID;
```

If I get a record, then I have the lock.

Otherwise, I could wait X seconds and try again later, up to a certain number of attempts.

Once I am done, I can release the lock with a simple Update statement

```
UPDATE SHARED.LOCK
  SET SESSION_ID = NULL
     ,ACQUIRED_AT = NULL
  WHERE LOCK_NAME = $LOCK_NAME
    AND SESSION_ID = $SESSION_ID;
```

And of course we'll have to do something about locks not released within a certain amount of time or locked by a session that is not live anymore, etc...

I think this should work... but maybe there is a simpler way to implement a singleton in Snowflake?

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on requirements, if the stored procedure is going to be run on schedule TASK could be used, which has OVERLAP protection built-in:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK my_task
  WAREHOUSE = compute_wh
  SCHEDULE = '1 minute'
  ALLOW_OVERLAPPING_EXECUTION = FALSE
AS  
CALL procedure_call();
```

[CREATE TASK - ALLOW_OVERLAPPING_EXECUTION](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task.html) :

> ```
> ALLOW_OVERLAPPING_EXECUTION = TRUE | FALSE
> ```
>
> Specifies whether to allow multiple instances of the task tree to run concurrently
>
> FALSE ensures **only one instance** of a particular tree of tasks is allowed to run at a time.

---

Demo:

```
CREATE TABLE log(id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1), d TIMESTAMP);

CREATE OR REPLACE procedure insert_log()
returns string
language javascript
execute as owner
as
$$
   snowflake.execute ({sqlText:  "INSERT INTO log (d) SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()"});
   snowflake.execute ({sqlText:  "CALL SYSTEM$WAIT(2, 'MINUTES')"});

   return "Succeeded.";   
$$
;

ALTER TASK my_task RESUME;

SELECT * FROM log;
```

Comment: I did not have in mind to use Tasks... but I'll have a look into it!

Thanks